# (Networking noob) I can't get network to work on a server using pfsense and juniper switch

Tags: networking, pfsense, juniper

I work at a company as an IT administrator, but my experience with networking is very limited. I was always focused on the OS and application side of things. Recently the only other IT administrator that worked here suddenly had to quit the job. The other bad news is that he was in the process of kind of modernizing and tidying up the server room ( removing redundant devices, switches, servers, etc). One of the major changes was upgrading the firewall from old Linux to a pfsense. To keep the story short - I need to continue his work in the server room. I tried to connect one of the servers to a new firewall ( pfsense), so here are the steps I took:

1. I connected the server with IP 192.105.58.108 to a Juniper EX2200 switch to port 24
2. I checked the configuration on an old firewall, which said that this server was connected to an interface with VLAN 472 and IP 192.105.58.97/27. I took this interface down
3. I added VLAN 472 with the name KD to a port in which this server is connected and to the port where pfsense is connected

> ```
> ge-0/0/24 {
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             vlan {
>                 members KD;
>             }
>
>
>  ge-0/0/21 {
>     unit 0 {
>         family ethernet-switching {
>             port-mode trunk;
>             vlan {
>                 members [ PFSENSE KD ];
>             }
> ```

4. In pfsense I added VLAN 472 and assigned it to the parent interface
5. I created a new interface assignment with IP 192.105.58.97/27 and assigned it to the newly created VLAN
6. Just to be sure I added a rule that allows my IP to access everything * on newly created interface.

What did I miss or what did I do wrong? Because I can't connect to that server, nor the pfsense can communicate with it. Any help would be appreciated.